# Is it possible to prove $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$ for strongly inaccessible $\kappa$ without AC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

First, let me note that my definition of "strongly inaccessible" is that a nonzero ordinal $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible if ${\rm cf}(\kappa)=\kappa$ and $\forall\alpha<\kappa, {\cal P}(\alpha)\prec\kappa$ in the sense of an injection from ${\cal P}(\alpha)$ to $\kappa$. (Thus $\omega$ is strongly inaccessible, although it is probably not important.)

The only way I know to prove that $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$ is to prove that $V_\alpha\prec\kappa$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$ by induction. If $V_\beta\prec\kappa$, then $|V_\beta|=\gamma$ for some $\gamma<\kappa$, and so $|V_{\beta+1}|=|{\cal P}(V_\beta)|=|{\cal P}(\gamma)|<\kappa$ since $\kappa$ is a strong limit. For limit ordinals $\alpha<\kappa$, $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta$, so since $V_\beta\prec\kappa$, $V_\alpha\preceq\alpha\times\kappa\prec\kappa\times\kappa\approx\kappa$ (where the inequalities correspond to injections and $\alpha\times\kappa$ is a cross product) by AC. Then we can finish by noting again that $V_\alpha\prec\kappa$ implies $V_\kappa=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}V_\alpha\preceq\bigsqcup_{\alpha<\kappa}\kappa=\kappa\times\kappa\approx\kappa$, and $\kappa\subseteq V_\kappa$ so that $V_\kappa\approx\kappa$ by Schroder-Bernstein.

In the proof above, I used AC twice, in the claim that $\forall \alpha<\kappa,A_\alpha\preceq B$ implies $\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}A_\alpha\preceq\kappa\times B$. Is it possible to generalize the approach of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395288/v-omega-is-countable) to avoid AC altogether? Also, it appears I only used the strong limit property above, without ever using the fact that $\kappa$ is regular. That can't be right; is it true that $|V(\beth_\omega)|=\beth_\omega$?

**Edit:** The above transfinite induction proof has a flaw in it in the limit step. For limit ordinals $\alpha<\kappa$, $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta$, so since $V_\beta\prec\kappa$, $V_\alpha\preceq\alpha\times\kappa\preceq\kappa\times\kappa\approx\kappa$ by AC, but the inequality is *not* strict. To make it strict, we note that if $|V_\alpha|=\kappa$, then the function $f:\alpha\to\kappa$ defined by $f(\beta)=|V_\beta|$ is a cofinal map, so ${\rm cf}(\kappa)=\kappa\le\alpha$, a contradiction. Thus $|V_\alpha|<\kappa$. So it is not true that strong limits are sufficient to ensure that $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$.

Comment: How is this "elementary"? :-)

Comment: @Asaf I feel like I just graduated. ;)

Comment: You’ve gone beyond elementary aleph and reached not-so-elementary beth. Just wait till you reach thoroughly-mysterious [gimel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimel_function)! :-)

Comment: @Brian: $\LaTeX$ has $\gimel$ and also $\daleth$, but I'm not aware of notational uses of the latter... (and it kinda looks like Resh anyway)

Comment: @Asaf: Did you check the link? It has a notational use of $\gimel$ that can be seen, for instance, in Jech’s *Set Theory* (p. $56$).

Comment: @Brian: I know about the $\gimel$ function since I was an undergrad and took a reading course about [very] basic PCF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, assuming choice one can show that $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$ (this addition is ordinal addition!), so we have $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$ if and only if $|\omega+\alpha|=|\alpha|=\beth_\alpha$ (note that this implies $\omega+\alpha=\alpha$ as ordinals). Inaccessible cardinals are indeed $\beth$ fixed points, but $\beth_\omega$ is certainly not.

So while there are fixed points which are singular, you still can't do that for any strong limit cardinal.

---

Now, to your main question. You can't adapt the proof from $\omega$ to an uncountable inaccessible $\kappa$, because that would mean that $V_\kappa\models\sf ZF+\text{Global Choice}$, because we can find a well-ordering of $V_\kappa$ internally definable within $V_\kappa$.

If we assume that $V_{\kappa+1}$ can be well-ordered, then this is not very difficult. The proof follows from **Theorem 11** and **Proposition 4** from the paper:

> Blass, Andreas, Ioanna Dimitriou, and Benedikt Lowe. **Inaccessible cardinals without the axiom of choice.** *Fundamenta mathematicae* **194**.2 (2007): 179-189.

You have to slightly adjust your construction as presented there, but it works. Alternatively, you can use the same proof as Jech gives (and attributes to Rubin & Rubin) in **Theorem 9.1 (b)** in his Axiom of Choice book.

---

Now, I haven't sat down to verify all the details, but it should probably work as a counterexample. And a contrived one too. The idea is based on Joel David Hamkins proof that [$\sf ZFC$ does not prove the universe can be linearly ordered.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110799/does-zfc-prove-the-universe-is-linearly-orderable)

Let $V$ be a model of $\sf ZFC$ and $\kappa\in V$ is inaccessible (for simplicity, assume $\sf GCH$ holds below $\kappa$). We consider the forcing $\Bbb P$ which add two subsets to each power set of a regular $\lambda<\kappa$ with functions whose domains are of cardinality $<\lambda$.

So a condition in $\Bbb P$ is a function $p\colon\kappa\times2\times\kappa\to 2$ with the following properties:

1. If $(\alpha,i,\beta)\in\operatorname{dom}(p)$ then $\beta<\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, and $i<2$.
2. The set $\{\beta<\aleph_{\alpha+1}\mid (\alpha,i,\beta)\in\operatorname{dom}(p)\}$ has size of at most $\aleph_\alpha$.
3. $|p|<\kappa$.

Now consider the automorphisms which "switch" the middle coordinate, $i$, separately between each $\alpha$. Informally, if $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ are the new subsets of $2^{\aleph_{\alpha+1}}$ then we just switch these two.

And let $\cal F$ be the filter of subgroups of bounded permutations, that is things which are fixed by a permutations which leave the $i$ coordinate intact for $i>i_0$ for some $i_0$. And let $N$ be the symmetric extension induced by $\cal F$.

It is not hard to show that $\kappa$ is still inaccessible in $N$. And it is not hard to show that the set $R=\{A_\alpha,B_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\}$ is also in $N$. But it cannot be linearly ordered in $N$.

Since $R\subseteq V_\kappa$ we have that it is impossible that $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$ in $N$.

Comment: I might be screwing up with the definition of the forcing, and it should be functions whose domain is $(\alpha,i,\beta,\gamma)$. Or maybe something else? I'm not sure. Let me know if you catch a mistake there (it should be inconsequential to the final result, though).

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of forcing arguments, which I find to be of a rather different character than standard set thoeretical arguments (it's always harder to prove something is unprovable than provable...). I did want to ask about your first paragraph, though. I'm not claiming that $\beth_\omega$ is strongly inaccessible; obviously it isn't. I claimed instead that my ZFC proof that $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$ apparently works for strong limits, not just strong inaccessibles, and $\beth_\omega$ is a strong limit, so $|V_{\beth_\omega}|=\beth_\omega$. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mario: Yes, I very much disagree. You can prove by transfinite recursion the formula that I gave is true, and therefore $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$ holds only for fixed points of the $\beth$ function, not for strong limits in general.

Comment: I don't follow. In ZFC, I get that $|V_{\omega+\alpha}|=\beth_\alpha$, and I also get that if $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, then $\beth_\kappa=\kappa$ (so $\beth_\omega$ is not inaccessible). But is there a fault in my proof, assuming AC? I didn't prove that $\alpha$ is inaccessible iff $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$ -- I only proved one direction of implication, and I realized later that I didn't even use the full strength of the hypothesis, so I can say now that "if $\alpha$ is a strong limit, then $|V_\alpha|=\alpha$". The only way this could be false is if there is a flaw in my proof.

Comment: Oh, I was completely missing your point. You are right, and there is a flaw in my proof: $\alpha<\kappa$ does not imply $\alpha\times\kappa\prec\kappa\times\kappa$. I believe the correct argument at limit stages is to note that since $V_\beta\prec\kappa$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, if $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}|V_\beta|=\kappa$, then $f(\beta)=|V_\beta|$ is a cofinal map onto $\kappa$, a contradiction (here we use that $\kappa$ is regular). But how do we know that $|V_\alpha|=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}|V_\beta|$?

Comment: @Mario: I don't understand your last comment. (And I missed your previous one, too.)

Comment: @Mario: I think that the flaw in your argument is assuming that without the axiom of choice it holds that $|\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} A_\beta|=\alpha\times\sup\{|A_\beta|\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

Comment: I'm trying to patch up my proof in the OP, which has a problem in it which was making me think that $|V_{\beth_\omega}|=\beth_\omega$ (in fact $|V_{\beth_\omega}|=\beth_{\beth_\omega}$). I know that the union bound needs to use AC, which I recognize in the OP, but I have a mistake in there that says $\alpha\prec\kappa$ implies $\alpha\times\kappa\prec\kappa\times\kappa$, which is incorrect: $2<\omega$, but $2\times\omega=\omega\times\omega$. (con't)

Comment: The correct proof needs to use that $\kappa$ is regular, and for limit $\alpha$ we know that $|V_\alpha|=|\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}V_\beta|\le|\kappa\times\alpha|=\kappa$ (I used the union bound there). But if $|V_\alpha|=\kappa$, then the sizes of $|V_\beta|$ less than $\kappa$ make a cofinal map, so ${\rm cf}(\kappa)\le\alpha<\kappa$, a contradiction. Thus $|V_\alpha|<\kappa$, and the transfinite induction continues all the way to $\kappa$.

Comment: @Mario: I'm not sure if it's the extremely odd sleep pattern of the last three days, or something else. I still don't understand fully what you're talking about...

Comment: I think I'm going to need to sleep on your forcing argument to understand it, so I guess we're even. ;-)

Comment: Good luck with that. Sleeping on that seems to be *very* uncomfortable. I'd only do that if someone forced me to do it... :-P